# Robocopy ran out of memory

Tags: batch-file

In a batch script, I have used Robocopy to delete older files. It was working before, but now am getting the below error.

```
ERROR : You do not have the Backup and Restore Files user rights.
*****  You need these to perform Backup copies (/B or /ZB).

ERROR : Robocopy ran out of memory, exiting.
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #%d : "%s"

ERROR : Invalid Job File, Line #%d :"%s"
Started : %s %s
Source %c 
 Dest %c 
 Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?
```

Pls advise.

I have used below command to remove older files.

```bash
robocopy %Source% %Target% *.* /MOV /S /zb /MINAGE:%MinAge% /CREATE /R:0 /W:0

rd %Target%
```

Comment: How about you provide the actual content of the variables, and how they were defined then the actual content of the output from the error, instead of replacing things which do not affect your privacy or security.